# Differentiating under an integral - applying the mean-value theorem to derive equation (2.4.4) in Casella and Berger (2003).

Tags: real-analysis, integration, statistics, derivatives

I am having difficulty unpacking the specifics of a set of conditions under which differentiation and integration can commute when the range of integration is infinite in [*Statistical Inference, Casella and Berger (2003)*](https://fsalamri.files.wordpress.com/2015/02/casella_berger_statistical_inference1.pdf).

*In particular, I would appreciate some clarity on applying the mean value theorem to get from condition (i) of Theorem 2.4.3, to equation (2.4.4). I am not soliciting answers that have recourse to the most general form of Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem as I do not possess the relevant tools in analysis and measure theory. The material presented in Casella and Berger is presented in such a way so as to explicitly avoid this, and therefore only presents watered-down corollaries of the theorem.*

**Context.**

Here is the relevant extract from Casella and Berger (2003) page 70:

> *Theorem 2.4.3. Suppose that $f(x, \theta)$ is differentiable at $\theta_0$, that is,*
>
> $$\lim_{\delta \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x, \theta_0 + \delta) - f(x, \theta_0)}{\delta} = \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} f(x, \theta) \Big \vert_{\theta = \theta_0}$$
>
> *exists for every $x$ and there exists a function $g(x, \theta_0)$ and a constant $\delta_0 > 0$ such that*
>
> i. $\Big \vert \frac{f(x, \theta_0 + \delta) - f(x, \theta_0)}{\delta} \Big \vert \leq g(x, \theta_0)$ *for all $x$ and* $\lvert \delta \rvert \leq \delta_0,$
>
> ii. $\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} g(x) \space dx < \infty.$
>
> *Then*
>
> $$\frac{d}{d \theta} \int^{\infty}_{-\infty} f(x, \theta) \space dx \Big \vert_{\theta = \theta_0} = \int^{\infty}_{-\infty} \Bigg [ \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} f(x, \theta) \Big \vert_{\theta = \theta_0} \Bigg] \space dx.$$

The authors then go on to say:

> Typically $f(x, \theta)$ is differentiable at all $\theta$, not at just one value $\theta_0$. In this case, condition (i) of Theorem 2.4.3 can be replaced by another condition that often proves easier to verify. By an application of the mean value theorem, it follows that for fixed $x$ and $\theta_0$, and $\lvert \delta \rvert \leq \delta_0$,
> $$\frac{f(x, \theta_0 + \delta) - f(x, \theta_0)}{\delta} = \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} f(x, \theta) \Big \vert_{\theta = \theta_0 + \delta^*(x)}$$
>
> for some number $\delta^*(x)$ where $\lvert \delta^*(x) \rvert \leq \delta_0$. Therefore condition (i) will be satisfied if we find a $g(x, \theta)$ that satisfies condition (ii) and
> $$\Bigg \vert \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} f(x, \theta) \Big \vert_{\theta = \theta'} \Bigg \vert \leq g(x, \theta) \quad \text{for all} \space \theta' \space \text{such that} \lvert \theta' - \theta \rvert \leq \delta_0. \tag{2.4.4}$$
> Note that in $(2.4.4)$, $\delta_0$ is implicitly a function of $\theta$, as is the case in Theorem 2.4.3. This is permitted since the theorem is applied to each value of $\theta$ individually.

**Queries.**

1. Why is $\delta^*(x)$ a function of $x$?

2. In equation (2.4.4), where $\theta'$ is now allowed to vary in the interval $(\theta - \delta_0, \theta + \delta_0)$, what is the corresponding interval over which the mean-value theorem is applied? Is it possible for the endpoints of the interval over which the mean-value theorem is applied to lie *outside* the interval $(\theta - \delta_0, \theta + \delta_0)$?

3. What is the significance of the constant $\delta_0 > 0$ in condition $(i)$ of Theorem 2.4.3 and equation (2.4.4)?

4. Why is it the case that $\delta_0$ is implicitly a function of $\theta$ in both condition $(i)$ of Theorem 2.4.3. and equation (2.4.4).

*I would be happy, on request, to supply further information about my understanding, or diagrams I have drawn, if that may help in understanding why I have asked the questions in the first place.*